# FSCalendar - Change the title color of Particular Dates Using Swift

Tags: swift, fscalendar

Hello all I'm working on the WenchaoD's FSCalendar now a days.I successfully loaded the calendar with many events.But now the question is how to change the date's title color for particular dates.Can anyone suggest me how to do this?

Comment: Please put the concerned code in the question.

Comment: will surely update my code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1) First of all implement **FSCalendarDelegateAppearance**

2) Let's assume you are having an array of some dates,let's declare an array first.

```
var somedays : Array = [String]()
```

3) Now you will need formatter to change the string into date.

```
fileprivate let gregorian: Calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
fileprivate lazy var dateFormatter1: DateFormatter = {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    return formatter
}()
```

4) FSCalendarDelegateAppearance is having one method named : **titleDefaultColorFor**

5) Implement this method using below code.

```
func calendar(_ calendar: FSCalendar, appearance: FSCalendarAppearance, titleDefaultColorFor date: Date) -> UIColor? {

    somedays = ["2017-06-03",
                "2017-06-06",
                "2017-06-12",
                "2017-06-25"]
    let dateString : String = dateFormatter1.string(from:date)

    if self.somedays.contains(dateString) {
        return .green
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

6) Run this code.Happy coding.

Comment: your code worked for me.Thanks.

Comment: welcome.please accept my answer by clicking on checkmark.